# For similar X compare Y values

Tags: matlab, sorting, coordinates, average

I am a newbie in MATLAB and I have the following problem:

I have a set of x,y,z coordinates something like this:

```
A=
1.01 3.45 5
1.02 9.38 5
1.02 3.51 6
...

9.05 2.85 50
9.91 2.21 50
10.05 2.23 51;
```

I want to find average x,y,z for the points which are nearby. z value will be different. i.e. in the above data set first and 3rd points are nearby. I need to combine them to there average centre of mass position. 
I was using the following code:

```
thresh= 5 % for z values only
B = sortrows(A,[1,2]);
difference = diff([0 0 0; A],1,1);
mask = (abs(difference(:,1)) < 2) & (abs(difference(:,2)) < 2) & (abs(difference(:,3)) < thresh);
subs = cumsum(~mask);
xmean = accumarray(subs,B(:,1),[],@mean);
ymean = accumarray(subs,B(:,2),[],@mean);
```

If I am using sortrows then I am not getting the desired result because of the second point.

I tried running sortrows multiple times as [1,2] and [2,1]. It helps but I can't get rid of all the overlapping points because in between there are values like the second point which have same x (or y) but y (or x) values not in the threshold and the diff cannot give the desired result in such case.

So, I was thinking if I can scan for a range of x values (like 1-1.02) I can get the difference of all corresponding y values. i. e. if there are 3 y values like the first 3 points, it will calculate diff(y1,y2), diff(y1,y3) and diff (y2-y3). Then generate average y value for the diffs which are less than the threshold.

I meant if the distance is <2 then the points are close to each other. The output I am expecting for the first three data points:

```
 1.015 3.48 5.5
 1.02 9.38 5
```

where the first point is the average of the first and third point of the input. Those two points were close to each other. But the second point is different so no change is required for that.

Similarly for the last three points, second and third point should be merged to one point because they are close. But not the first and second one because the z values of them are same. What I need is for different z values, find close points where diff x < 2 and diff y < 2 and get the average position. But I don't need to merge those points who are having same z value but similar x,y.

Somebody please help.

Comment: How do you classify a point as near? Is it if they are the distance is `< 2`? It would also be good if you posted the expected output.

Comment: Yes, I meant if  the distance is <2 then the points are close to each other. The output I am expecting for the first three data points: 1.015 3.48 5.5; 1.02 9.38 5....where the first point is the average of the first and third point of the input. Those two points were close to each other. But the second point is different so no change is required for that. @kkuilla I hope I have cleared your doubt.

Comment: Similarly for the last three points, second and third point should be merged to one point because they are close.  But not the first and second one because the z values of them are same. What I need is for different z values, find close points where diff x < 2 and diff y < 2 and get the average position. But I don't need to merge those points who are having same z value but similar x,y. @kkuilla

Comment: Please update your question with the information.

Comment: why aren't you using `kmeans`?

Comment: I believe for kmeans I need to specify the number of groups which is tricky here. For different z values, only few points are repeating (or having similar values). By using kmeans I may loose data points. For example: in case of last 3 points I'll get only 1 point by using kmeans whereas I need the programme to return 2 points: 1st point and average of 2nd and 3rd point. @Shai If you can suggest some way so that I can only specifically get the average of the repeating (similar value) points that would be really helpful.

Comment: You can run aggregative clustering only on `x` and `y` coordinates and then average using `accumarray`.

Comment: I think in that case also I'll loose some points if I don't consider z. As I mentioned earlier, for the last three points. Can you elaborate more on what you suggested? @Shai